# I'm trying to capture JavaScript from the clipboard and execute in to run on a webpage in Chrome

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I have JavaScript that works when ran as a Bookmarklet. So, I know the code works.

However, I'm trying to avoid having to paste the bookmarklet to the bookmarks bar every time the code changes. The code changes on every document that we create, from our MIS system.

I want to be able to execute the JavaScript from the clipboard. Here's how I'm trying to do this:

```
javascript: window.focus();setTimeout(async () => {
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  console.log(text);eval(text);
}, 2000);
```

It seems simple, get the text from the clipboard, then run it.

I know the text is being captured from the clipboard, because it is showing up on the console log.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be aware of [`eval()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-javascripts-eval-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into how I feel this is a spectacularly bad idea from a security perspective. I'm not aware of your environment so perhaps you have some means to ensure no malicious code ends up in the clipboard.

Perhaps CSP is blocking eval. If so you'll need to add the "unsafe-eval" value to the CSP. Are there any console log errors?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've wrestled with the security perspective. The only information that is being copied is Company name, address, email, invoice amounts, etc. I am simply getting info out of a MIS system to an invoicing system. No credit cards, no SSN... nothing like that at all.